# Storing data on Filter Selections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, data-structures, filter

My doubt is regarding Filter Screen.

I want to store & remove data which user selected & deselected from Filter Screen respectively. I am not sure what data type to use here.

As it appears from below image :
Suppose I have Few filter headings like "Category", "Color", "Unit",etc.
& inside of every heading i have some values like in category I have values from category 1, category 2... upto category 50.
Now when user selects anything like Category2, category3.. I can store those particular values in Array, but when user deselect any category(unchecking the checkboxes) randomly then how i will be able to remove that particular value from array because i can't get related index inside array.(means like user selected some 10 categories then i have some 10 values inside my array but thay are not matched indexwise with values from tableView index.)
Assist me on how to approach this..[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how i would approach the problem. Assuming i have a data source which would contain the items without applying any filter. (In practice this is not how it would be, you would probably be getting your data source via network calls) Once a user applies or removes a filter by checking or unchecking the checkbox, i would filter the data source with the active filters.

Let's say this is your item class.

```
class Item {
    var category: Category
    var color: Color
}

enum Category {
    case one
    case two
    .
    .
    case none
}

// Similarly for color and other parameters
```

Now this would be your filter object that maintains all the filters that are active.

```
class FilterParameters {
    var category: [Category]? = nil
    var color: [Color]? = nil
}
```

Create an object of this class and every time a filter is checked or unchecked, filter your data source with the current active filters. (If a filter is not selected then ignore that filter and construct filter parameters based on the ones you do have).